# Display records not matching in where clause

Tags: oracle11g

I need to display records not matching the where clause.

Example - `select * from citytable where city in ('aa','bb','cc', 'dd','ee');`

only `aa`, `bb`, `cc` are present in table, `dd` & `ee` are not present in the table. However, I still need to display `dd` & `ee`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are probably looking for something like this. An IN condition is the same as an inner join to a table containing the unique (distinct) values from the IN list. What you want is an outer join. You need to have a table instead of the IN list. In the solution below I show how you can create this "helper" table on the fly; there are several other methods, this just demonstrates the idea.

```
select deptno, ename from emp where deptno in (10, 50, 80);

DEPTNO  ENAME
------  ------
10      CLARK
10      KING
10      MILLER


with h ( deptno ) as (
  select 10 from dual union all
  select 50 from dual union all
  select 80 from dual
)
select h.deptno, e.ename
from h left outer join emp e
on h.deptno = e.deptno
;

DEPTNO  ENAME
------  ------
10      CLARK
10      KING
10      MILLER
50  
80
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure exactly how you want the output to look. If there is no data where city='ee', what exactly do you want to show? Something like this?

```
SELECT * FROM
(SELECT key AS A_key, one AS A_one, two AS A_two FROM cityTable WHERE one='aa') AS A
JOIN
(SELECT key AS E_key, one AS E_one, two AS E_two FROM cityTable WHERE one='ee') AS E
ON A_key=E_key 
...etc.
```

Edit: or maybe this is it:
`SELECT city FROM (SELECT city, count(*) AS c FROM cityTable GROUP BY city) WHERE c = 0`

Comment: Following should be clear ---
*********************************************
CityTable 
 
City Country
aa AA
bb BB
cc CC
********************************************* 
my query - select * from citytable where city in ('aa','bb','cc', 'dd','ee'); 
********************************************* 
Output Required- 
City 
dd 
ee 
*********************************************

Comment: apologies for the typo.....my output should be the values which didnt return any record in where clause.......that is dd & ee only

Comment: `SELECT city FROM (SELECT city, count(*) AS c FROM cityTable GROUP BY city) WHERE c = 0` ?

Answer (score 0):

As i understand you said the `'dd'` amd `'ee'` are not present in the table but you still need it so you can achieve it using a `union all`. But remember that the columns of the 'dd' and 'ee' rows will always be null since there is no records present in your `citytable`

```
SELECT ct.col1 AS city, ct.col2.....<all columns of your table>
    from citytable ct
    where city in ('aa','bb','cc')
    UNION ALL
    select 'dd' as city,null ,null.....<nulls as many times as the number of columns of your table>
    from citytable ct1
    UNION ALL
    select 'ee' as city,null ,null.....<nulls as many times as the number of columns of your table>
    from citytable ct2
```